# Can I release the source code of a game created with the personal edition of Unity?

Tags: unity

Does the license of Unity Personal allow the publishing of the game's source code? We want to develop a game on a hackathon and publish the code thereafter. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you read the license?

Comment: If Unity's license said they own the source code you write, they'd have been sued into oblivion years ago.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can release the scripts you write. The source code is not actually created by Unity (of any edition). It's created by you, you own it.

You can write the source code using whatever editor you like from notepad to Monodevelop. These are just tools to help you write code, using them does not mean the creators of those tools own your source.

However, when you compile that code, you're compiling it with Unity's code. This is where their license comes into play. This is the difference between the paid and free versions of Unity, because you're licensing their code to run your code.

Releasing your own code that makes calls to Unity code is fine. You're not releasing their source code, only your code that makes use of it.

Please note that this assumes you are the one writing the code, and you're not being paid to do so. Further, it assumes you're not in any contracts with an employer that might give them rights to code you write in your free time (this may be the case if you worked on very similar code at work for example).

Comment: I have a similar question not so trivial though. What about licenses in general? Do you know if I can put it under MIT-License or is it copyleft or sth similar hindering me to put it under a license of my choice+?

Comment: I'd have to read the license terms. I suggest you do that.